# What is a stream exactly?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

When my book says : a stream is a sequence of characters read or written from a device then my book says : the `istream` and the `ostream` types represent input and output stream ( what does it mean ?) how exactly do `cout` and `cin` work?

I'm not a language native and I can't understand when my book says : the output operator writes the given value on the given `ostream`.

Comment: steams can be bi-directional, or uni-directional. that's all

Comment: get a good overview of the stream classes here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/

Answer (score 21):

The fundamental idea behind the metaphor of a "stream" is that it provides or consumes data in a *single-pass* fashion: for example, for an input stream, data is produced precisely *once*. You can ask the stream for some more data, and once the stream has given you the data, it will never give you that same data again.

This is why in order to do anything meaningful with streams, you will very usually want to attach a kind of *buffer* (a "stream buffer", if you will) to the stream which stores some (usually small) amount of data that's been extracted from the stream in a random-access, inspectable and processable piece of memory. (There are similar, reversed ideas for output streams.)

Occasionally it makes sense to process streams without any buffering. For example, if you have an input and an output stream and you read integers from the input and write the doubled value of each integer to the output, you can do that without buffering.

So when thinking about *ranges* of data, streams are things that you can traverse only once and never again. If you're thinking in terms of forward progress, then streams have another property, which is that they may *block*: an input stream may block when it has no data, and an output stream may block when it cannot accept any more data. That way, from within the program logic, you can imagine that a input stream *always* contains data until its end is reached, but a program relying on that may run for an arbitrary, unbounded amount of wall-clock time.

Comment: Might be useful to point out that the terminal history as displayed via a CRT (or modern equivalent (lol)) is a buffer in this context.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I like this part of your answer .... that clarify me streaming as concept... specially "single-pass fashion" ... thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can define it in simple words as the flow of data which can be the input flow and output flow. So you can think of it as the flow of data from a program to a file or vice versa. The below image may help you understand it better:

[image]

[image]

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t047d21k.aspx)

> The stream is the central concept of the iostream classes. You can
>   think of a stream object as a smart file that acts as a source and
>   destination for bytes. A stream's characteristics are determined by
>   its class and by customized insertion and extraction operators.

Answer (score 3):

From a language point of view, streams are just objects with a certain streamlike interface: they allow you to extract data from it (an input stream) or to push data into it (an output stream). Input streams do not allow random access (whatever that may mean) to the data they provide (whatever that might be).

Note that this is purely an interface description for a class, nothing more. Where the stream gets its data from / what it does with the data pushed into it, is entirely up to the stream. A stream is an abstraction for recieving/sending data.

A concrete implementation of a stream may read data from a terminal application and present it to the program (`cin`), another one may return characters to the terminal application as the program requests (`cout`), a third one may read/write data from/to a file (the `fstream`s), a fourth one may read/write data from/to a memory buffer (`stringstream`), a fifth one may "read" data from a random number generator, and so on. The possibility are numerous, as are the different implementations of the stream interface that have been created.

That is the beauty of the abstraction of streams: it is a very flexible way for a piece of code to communicate. The process does not need to know anything about the source/destination of its data, other than that it can read/write data from/to it.

Answer (score 0):

A stream is a logical abstraction of physical file(regular file or device file) for IO operations. In Unix, a stream is a pointer to _IO_FILE structure defined in glibc. The _IO_FILE structure given by the OS stores attributes of the opening file. Application program operates(read, write, seek, and etc) on these file attributes to access data in the file.

You can build all type of streams (char stream, byte stream, input stream, output stream, or even bidirectional stream) on top of the above stream concept.  They are all implementations or wrappers/decorators of the above stream.

Comment: This is a general, fairly abstract question; be careful about assuming what platform OP is on.

Comment: I.M.H.O. that is exactly what makes stream so difficult to understand - there are so many implementations of it and each has its own definition. So, I kind of fall back to K&R C and Unix where everything started.

Comment: Can you please clear my doubts about stream by answering bellows. 1#is stream the name of a specific memory region?  2# or it works like normal object like c++,  I mean when we make a object of stream related classes like istream, ostream, iostream the object takes memory in the ram and do whatever properties and behavior given in the class body.

Comment: Basically, user program can not access memory or any hardware without help of OS. To simply put, when you run a C++ program, the compiler will transfer the program into native code, and the OS will load/linking the native code ( including the stream objects you mentioned) at run time where configurations are made.  I believe there are ways and circumstances where user can access "specific memory region", but it will be a long story.